# How to use PHP Load Data Infile to replace the current copy of the table with the new one?

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile

We get a new copy of data in a pipe-delimited text file from time to time. I have to refresh the table or in other words, replace the existing copy with that of the newly generated copy (output.txt).

Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thank you..

```
TRUNCATE Table elements;

LOAD DATA INFILE '/data/out.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE elements FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (ID, Title, date, time);
```

Comment: A bit more info would be nice. Do you want the data to refresh in real time, using AJAX? What is the format of the data like, and do you have some code ready?

Comment: I don't want to complicate it with AJAX, it is already in a complicated stage as is! I needed to develop a simple hack to synchronize a MySQL and MS SQL database (which reside on Linux and Windows hosts respectively). I think I finally got the solution. Updated it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree more information is needed to answer your question. As I understand it you need to empty a database table and reload it with the information in the text file you received, which sounds like a CSV file that uses pipes instead of commas. Do I have this right?

So you need to...

**Step 1 - Get your information out of the text file.**
You can try something like fgetcsv() (setting the delimiter to '|'), or you could just use fgets() and use explode() to put the data in an array.

**Step 2 - Insert data into your database table**
Loop through you data until you have it all in there. If all goes well then...

**Step 3 - Delete the old data**
It might seem easier to empty the database first, and then add your data. You could do that, but if something goes wrong with the new data then what? Now you're stuck with an empty database table until you fix it. Depending on what this is used for that could be undesirable.

Comment: Thank you! I tried Truncating the table first and then processing the load which, as you said can fail sometimes. Can we we do an insert ignore using Load data infile?

Comment: If you don't have an easy way to figure out which data to delete after the fact you could just do everything in a transaction(deleting first), and roll back your changes if it doesn't go well.